# Conditional filter on list

Tags: c#, linq

```
var dbRecords = (from c ...... query removed).Where(c => c.BNumber.Contains(bnum)).ToList();

// At this point dbRecords contains 596 records

int chkCount = 0;

// I have a series of checkboxes for filtering of the query

foreach (ListItem c in chklColumns.Items)
{
    if (c.Selected == true)
    {
        chkCount++;
    }
    if (chkCount > 0)
    {
        foreach (ListItem x in chklColumns.Items)
        {
            var gridKey = "Grp" + x.Value;

            if (x.Selected)
            {
               if (gridKey == "GrpSOS")
               {
                   dbRecords.Where(p => p.SOSEnabledYN == true);
               }
               if (gridKey == "GrpMOB")
               {
                   dbRecords.Where(p => p.ZMobileEnabledYN == true);

                   // If this filter were applied then my resultset would be 276 records
                   // I step through and hit this code but it does not seem to be affecting the dbRecords list
               }
               if (gridKey == "GrpPHO")
               {
                   dbRecords.Where(p => p.PhoneMonitorEnabledYN == true);
               }
           }
       }
   }

WebDataGrid1.DataSource = dbRecords;
WebDataGrid1.DataBind();
```

After filtering with the Where statement for each checkbox I bind to the grid - but it is always the same count of records - almost like the filters were not being applied.  Why is the dbRecords not being adjusted by the Where statements?

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it will be for users to help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Where()` returns a new filtered list, it does not not modifies the original list so you need to store the filtered list like this:

```
dbRecords = dbRecords.Where(p => p.SOSEnabledYN == true);
```

### EXAMPLE:

```
List<User> myUsers = New List<User>();
//fill the list myUsers with some User object
List<User> activeUsers = myUsers.Where(u => u.Active == True);
//the activeUsers list will contain only active users filtered from list of all users
```

Comment: Thanks - I had tried to do this but i had Tolist on my original query.  Once I removed that I was able to reassign the dbRecords.